# Why MongoDB exclude the end date when filtering with start date and end date

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to filter data by start date and end date with aggregation. This is the query i am using

```
{
  $and: [
  { createdAt: { $gte: ISODate('2023-04-10T18:30:00.000Z')}},
  { createdAt: { $lte: ISODate('2023-04-18T00:00:00.000Z')}}  
  ]
}
```

I am only getting results between 10-17 april.It is excluding 18 april. The stored dates in mongodb are similar to this `2023-04-18T11:41:45.303+00:00` . What could be the issue here??

Comment: Do you store values as text?

Comment: Because `2023-04-18T11:41:45.303+00:00` is after `2023-04-18T00:00:00.000Z`. So it is excluded for the search range. Unless your end date is `2023-04-19`, then it is within the search range.

Comment: @YongShun Thanks.I passed the end of the day to it. Worked perfectly